# How to return an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, random

I've been having a problem for the last few hours… I cannot find a answer anywhere so was hoping someone could help me here.

I do not completely understand how i should go about creating an array method that picks random numbers from a method and then displays them in the main method.

The main problem i have been having is how to transfer the method with the random 10 variables in order to substitute the array in the main method so i may display them through the main method?

If any further information is needed please let me know… I really appreciate any help.

the following is just something random i put together that i tried, but doesn't work… i cannot seem to get the method array to compile and transfer to the main method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class oneDimensionArraysNew {
public static void main (String [] args) {

    //Declare and create array    
    int[] aVariable =  new int[10];

    randomValues (aVariable);

    System.out.print("Your random variables are" + aVariable);
  }

    public static double randomValues (int random1 []) {
   int[] randomSet = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < randomSet.length; i++) {
        randomSet[i] = (int) Math.random() * 100;//teacher did not specify max
        return randomSet;
```

Comment: you are maiking a int[] why return double[]?:S

Comment: You also do not use the random1 parameter. Is that intentional?

Comment: I completely forgot to change that… after so long i did not even notice it… although the problem now would be to get a return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send back the array. Follow this snippet

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

  //Declare and create array    
  int[] aVariable =  new int[10];
  int[] updatedaVariable = new int[10];

  updatedaVariable = randomValues (aVariable);
  System.out.print("Your random variables are ");

  for(int i : updatedaVariable)
  {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
  }
}

public static int[] randomValues (int random1 []) {
  int[] randomSet = new int[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < randomSet.length; i++) {
      randomSet[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);//teacher did not specify max
  }
  return randomSet;
}
```

Comment: When i compile and run the program returns some numbers, letter and characters (ex: [I@393e6226) Any idea if it has something to do with math.random ?

Comment: its because you are printing the array, extract the numbers and print them !

Comment: this method returns 0,0,0,0,0… without any variables changing

Comment: It is because you are type casting double to int before the mutiplication. Use `(int) (Math.random() * 100)`

Comment: This worked the best! just want to ask seeing from everyone else's answers would it be wise to keep both arrays for a main and a second method? I'm planning on adding on about 7 more methods that would do different functions with the random numbers?

Comment: IMHO, you are not using `aVariable` in the method at all. So you can just remove it ! The whole thing will work, without it as well !

Answer (score 2):

Either you return a new array by creating one in the method `randomValues` (in which case you have to adjust the return type), or you fill the array you have passed in via parameter and return nothing.

Comment: Sorry, you missed what? :-D

Comment: The fact that he is taking an array as argument, creating another array and returning it.. Was just looking at the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the size of the array of random numbers as an argument to the method, instead of passing an array as you are right now. Also, return a `double[]` instead of a single `double` if you want to return an array:

```
    public static double[] randomValues (int length) {
    int[] randomSet = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        randomSet[i] = (int) Math.random() * 100;//teacher did not specify max
    }
    return randomSet;
    }
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

change line:

```
public static double randomValues (int random1 [])
```

with

```
public static int[] randomValues (int random1 []) 
or
public static double[] randomValues (int random1 []) {
```